# Adding support for newlines (\n) in C

Tags: c

I have written a simple OS which I am compiling using QEMU in Linux. The terminal is printing a simple message on the screen (`"Hello World\n"`), however, the new line character (`\n`) is producing a strange character rather than inserting a new line after the message.

Here is the code I have written for `putchar`:

```
void putchar(char c) {
    putentryat(c, color, column, row);
    if (++column == WIDTH) {
        column = 0;
        if (++row == HEIGHT) {
            column = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Main function simply calling a `writestring` function which displays the message as shown in the below code.

```
void main() {
    initialize();
    writestring("Hello World\n");
}
```

At the moment the `n` is printing out garbage character as stdio.h is not supported by the program. I have tried adding `putchar('\n');` in `putchar` function after `putentryat(...)` but I am still getting the problem.

If somebody can provide tips on how I can resolve this problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is your string unicode or ansi?  What is the value of /n if you echo it to the screen as hex?  What's your codepage?

Comment: And is there a slash/backslash confusion?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider the  slash/backslash confusion looks like a typo to me.

Comment: The C compiler usually translates the `\n` backslash sequence in a character constant or string literal to an ASCII linefeed (LF) character, which is character code 10 (0xA). C calls it the new-line character. It is up to your OS's terminal driver how it interprets that character and other control characters. The C compiler for your OS might use a different new-line character than ASCII LF. Also, the C library for your OS might treat the new-line character specially for files opened in "text" mode, including the `stdout`, `stdin`, and `stderr` streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal handles some characters such as `\n` specifically to perform specific tasks:

- `\n` causes the cursor to move down one line, and possibly to go back to the leftmost column (`column = 0` in your case).
- `\r` should cause the cursor to move to the leftmost column on the current line.
- `\t` moves the cursor right to the next TAB stop, usually a multiple of 8 positions.
- `\f` could erase the screen and move the cursor to the home position.
- `\a` could cause the speaker to produce a beep or the screen to blink.

All these actions are performed instead of displaying a character at the current cursor position.  You must test the character value specifically to perform the special action instead of displaying the character.

Here is an example:

```
void term_putchar(int c) {
    switch (c) {
      case '\r':
        column = 0;
        break;
      case '\n':
        column = 0;
        row++;
        break;
      case '\t':
        column = (column + 8) / 8 * 8;
        if (column >= WIDTH) {
            column -= WIDTH;
            row++;
        }
        break;
      case '\f':
        term_erase_screen();
        column = row = 0;
        break;
      case '\a':
        term_beep();
        break;
      default:
        putentryat(c, color, column, row);
        if (++column == WIDTH) {
            column = 0;
            ++row;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (row == HEIGHT) {
        if (term_page_mode) {
            row = 0;
        } else {
            term_scroll_screen_up();
            row--;
        }
    }
    /* should update the blinking cursor on the screen screen */
}

int putchar(int c) {
    if (output_to_terminal) {
        term_putchar(c);
    } else {
        /* output to file? */
    }
    return c;
}
```

Note that real terminals have far more special characters to control output, screen handling, colors, cursor movement, flow control, etc. In addition to specific characters, they use escape sequences (`\e` followed by other characters).

Comment: The above code is just an example of how to handle terminal emulation. `term_page_mode` would be a global variable to select between page mode where the cursor goes to home position when it goes off the bottom edge of the screen and scroll mode where you would use `term_scroll_screen_up()` to move the window contents up by one line.  How you would implement that is your decision...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need this:

```
void putchar(char c){
   if (c == '\n') {
     column = 0;
     if (++row == HEIGHT) {
        // perform scroll 
     }
   }
   else  
      putentryat(c, color, column, row);

   if (++column == WIDTH) {
     column = 0;
     if (++row == HEIGHT) {
       // perform scroll
       column = 0;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong place for this.  It doesn't belong in the standard I/O library, and would cause problems if the output went to anything other than a terminal (e.g., a file).  Instead, the handling of newline characters belongs in the device driver for your terminal.

Comment: @TomKarzes sure, but at the OP's level it answers the question. Considering your comment, the OP's original approach is already wrong.

Comment: @user2977378 impossible to answer without knowing more about your output device. What exactly is `putentryat` ? Is tis part of some library ? If yes you should look in the documentation of that library.

Comment: @user2977378 what is `make_vgaentry` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Unfortunately, I am not able to paste the entire file on here but I am happy to send it to you via email if you want? 

This is what the make_vgaentry function does:
`uint16_t make_vgaentry(char c, uint8_t color) {
  uint16_t c16 = c;
  uint16_t color16 = color;
  return c16 | color16 << 8;
}
 `

Comment: @user2977378 I don't think anything. What exactly is `buffer`? What does `make_vgaentry` do? What is WIDTH and HEIGHT (I suppose WIDTH is 80 and HEIGHT is 25).

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes the Width and Height is 80 and 25 respectively. 

This what the term_initialize does; Buffer is in this function: 
`void terminal_initialize() {
  row = 0;
  column = 0;
  tcolor = color(COLOR_LIGHT_GREY, COLOR_BLACK); /*Terminal Background*/
  buffer = (uint16_t*) 0xB8000;
  for (size_t y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < VGA_WIDTH; x++) {
      const size_t index = y * WIDTH + x;
      buffer[index] = vgaentry(' ', terminal_color);
      buffer[y * WIDTH + x] = buffer[(y + 1) * WIDTH + x];
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @user2977378 no code in comments please, it's unreadable, update your question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Ok will do. Thanks

Comment: @user2977378 actually the scroll part is rather a new question. You should therefore ask a _new_ question.

Answer (score 3):

```
// ...
if (c == '\n') {
    column = 0;
    row++;
    // do not putentry
}
// ...
```